# How to realize a queue in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to set up a queue of functions in Darts. Queuing should be asynchronous, allowing multiple functions to run concurrently. However, a maximum of three functions should be executed simultaneously. How can I achieve this?

I already tied working off a list but i am struggeling at adding a limit on same time running functions

```
List<String> queue = new List();

main(){
  queue.add("...");
  queue.add("...");
  queue.add("...");

  for(String q in queue){
    await crawl(q);
  }
}

crawl(String) async{
   ...
}
```

Comment: There is a queue class for Dart https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-collection/Queue-class.html and Dart is single-threaded so there is no way 2 functions can modify the queue at the same time. All methods of the queue are sync and therefore atomic.  "Queuing should be asynchronous" not sure what that means.

Comment: "Queuing should be asynchronous". I'm trying to make a search engine in dart. Therefore i have to crawl through websites. For speeding up the process the program should crawl multiple websites at the same time.

Comment: "crawl multiple websites at the same time" that's fine. The adding/removing to the queue is very cheap and atomic and therefore no need for any specific precautions. Just add and remove to your desire. Is there any specific problem left?

Comment: Yes! :) "It is generally not allowed to modify the queue (add or remove entries) while an operation on the queue is being performed, for example during a call to forEach. Modifying the queue while it is being iterated will most likely break the iteration.". The crawler adds websites permanently

Comment: Then just copy the queue before iterating. `queue.toList().forEach(...)` You would need to elaborate how you would want conflicts to be handled.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a queue:

```
import "dart:collection";
final queue = Queue<String>();
main() {
  queue
    ..add("...")
    ..add("...")
    ..add("...");
  while (queue.isNotEmpty) {
    await crawl(queue.removeFirst());
  }
}

crawl(String x) async {
  .... queue.add(...) ...
}
```

This should work. It will *not* do concurrent crawling because await each operation. If you want concurrent crawling, I recommend being a little more clever. Look for worker pools or similar structures to ensure that you only have a certain number of operations running at the same time.